# Как передать в функцию двумерный массив неизвестной длины

Tags: delphi

Цель: передать двумерный массив в функцию неизвестной длины массива и неизвестными длинами его элементов.
Например: параметр функции (`Polygons: array of array of integer;`)
Передаём в функцию двумерный массив типа: `array[1..12, 1..3] of integer;`

P.S. Знаю про открытый массив, но с двумерными массивами использовать его не получается. По сути нужно сделать открытый массив открытых массивов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заранее объявите тип двумерного динамического массива и используйте этот тип при объявлении функции и при ее вызове

```
type
  TArr2d =array of array of integer;
```

Comment: Про типы я естественно знаю, но целью было передавать не только динамические, но и статические массивы, по аналогии с открытым массивом

Comment: Нет, такой технологии для двумерных нет. Для статических можно передавать адрес и размеры, но динамические одним куском не хранятся, поэтому простой единый подход неосуществим.